# 'java -cp' command line not working

Tags: java

i tried 'java -cp' command line to reference jar files.but for some reasons it doesn't work.FYI,java version on my machine is java1.8.

Later i tried '-Djava-ext-dirs' option and it works.
Is there any syntax error in the command?

[image]

[image]

and my folder hierarchy:
[image]
[image]

Comment: solved,problem is i didn't put <italic>;</italic> at the end of -cp option.Correct command is:<strong> java -cp lib/*; test.A</strong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The statement *You cannot use wildcards in the `-cp` paths.* is outdated. See @Heri's comment below.

You cannot use wildcards in the `-cp` paths. You have to list all jars separated by `;` on Windows or by `:` on Linux and macOS.

You can create a shell/command script to list the jars in your lib directory and populate the `-cp` option for you.

Comment: Since java 6 it _is_ possible to use wildcard. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Comment: @Heri: thank you for letting me know that, I'm too old for this ;)

Comment: solved,problem is i didn't put <italic>;</italic> at the end of -cp option.                                            Correct command is:<strong> java -cp lib/*; test.A</strong>